# MIPS assembly - subroutines and functions inquiry

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I'm fairly new at this type of "programming" so I've encountered some problems while creating a program. The program that I'm trying to create accepts two integers, n and r. If n is equal to r, OR r is equal to 0, the value of the output is 1. Otherwise, it will implement an f(n-1,r) + f(n-1,r-1) function.

Here's my code:

```
 .data 0x1001000C
 x: .word 4
 y: .word 2

 .text
 main: 
     sub $t3, $t3, $t3
     sub $t4, $t4, $t4
     lui $t0, 0x1001 
     lw $t1, 0($t0)      #this is your initial n 
     lw $t2, 4($t0)     #this is your initial r
     addi $a0, $t1, 0
     addi $a1, $t2, 0
     jal form_base 
     addi $t3, $v0, 0
     sw $t3, 0($t0)
     j main_exit

 main_exit:
     li $v0, 10
     syscall  

 form_base:                                   #this part checks the (n==r ||      r==0) OR otherwise 
    beq $a0,$a1, IF 
    bne $a1, $zero, form_recurse 
 IF:     
     addi $t4, $t4, 1
     addi $v0, $t4, 0  
     jr $ra

 form_recurse: 
     subu $sp, $sp, 20
     sw $ra, 4($sp)
     sw $a0, 8($sp)
     sw $a1, 12($sp)

     addi $a0, $a0, -1         #this is the n-1 part
     addi $a1, $a1, 0          #this is the r part 
     jal form_base
     sw $v0, 0($sp)

     addi $a0, $a0, -1        #this is the n-1 part
     addi $a1, $a1, -1        #this is the r-1 part 
     jal form_base

     lw $t0, 0($sp)
     add $v0,$t0,$v0         #final value of function 

     lw $ra, 4($sp)
     lw $a0, 8($sp)
     lw $a1, 12($sp)
     addu $sp, $sp, 20

         jr $ra
```

**GIVEN:** n is always greater or equal to r

**PROBLEM:** for 4 and 2, the answer should've been 6. However, this program outputs 1 instead, which means that it's terminating AFTER the f(n-1,r) function without proceeding to the f(n-1,r-1) function and so on.

What do I do to solve this problem? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Same homework assignment, different code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696519/mips-recursion-output-error

Comment: This looks like MARS/SPIM simulators kind of environment (judging by the syscall argument). Those have built-in debugger, so you can easily check yourself, why `f(n-1, r-1)` is not being called, or if it is, what arguments are passed, and what happens next.

Comment: *What do I do to solve this problem?*  You single-step through your code with a debugger to see where it branches in a way you don't want.  Or you sit and wait for someone else to answer your Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I can actually check the whole program step by step! I finally found out where I went wrong: the storing and loading of the n and r (4 and 2) values. I don't understand where I went wrong though.

Comment: If you have find the exact spot which you can't understand, **edit** your question, and give us enough details to replicate, i.e. what were your inputs, and at which point you get weird result, how you think it should work, and what you see it doing in reality. Then we can try to guess which of your assumptions is wrong and which part of CPU you misunderstood, and help you to understand it better. Once you will understand *why* your code is wrong, you will very likely easily fix it yourself, so that's why I'm personally more interested into how you understand it now - to fix that, not code.